# Google Sitemap and Robots.txt Issue

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt

We have a sitemap at our site, http://www.gamezebo.com/sitemap.xml

Some of the urls in the sitemap, are being reported in the webmaster central as being blocked by our robots.txt, see, [gamezebo.com/robots.txt](http://www.gamezebo.com/robots.txt) ! Although these urls are not Disallowed in Robots.txt. There are other such urls aswell, for example, gamezebo.com/gamelinks is present in our sitemap, but it's being reported as "URL restricted by robots.txt".

Also I have this parse result in the Webmaster Central that says, "Line 21: Crawl-delay: 10     Rule ignored by Googlebot". What does it mean?

I appreciate your help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the crawl delay is not an actual specification in robots.txt format so that line will be ignored... you can set a custom crawl rate if you want to in [google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) under settings > crawl rate